# condensing row data into one row based on column value(s)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a large data set, originally in XLSX. It started with all of the values in just a couple columns, which I've split into individual columns. Not all columns have values for every record, so I put place holders of `@` in those cells, as that symbol did not occur anywhere in the data. Ultimately those can be replaced with empty strings.

I want each "record" to be just one row, based on `record number`, and every row that matches that record number needs to be included.
Every record has a date and a unique `complaint number`. The original dataset has more like 12 columns, most values are strings. I left the `NaN` cells, but they can be filled with empty strings, if need be, and will be ultimately.

```
    record number   date      city_1    county_1 zip_code_1   city_2 county_2 zip_code_2 complaint_number 
0   1              01/01/2009  Nan      NaN         NaN       Nan     NaN    NaN   NaN     NaN
1   1              NaN        CityVille Nan         NaN       NaN     NaN    NaN   NaN     NaN
2   1              Nan         NaN     CountyVille  NaN       NaN     NaN    NaN   Nan     NaN 
3   1              NaN         NaN      NaN           @       @       NaN    NaN   NaN     NaN
4   1              NaN         NaN      NaN         01112   NaN        NaN   @     NaN     CN111112  
5   2              02/01/2009  CityTown NaN         NaN     NaN        NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN    
6   2              NaN         NaN      TownCounty  NaN     NaN        NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN
7   2              NaN         NaN      NaN         02223   NaN        NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN
8   2              NaN         NaN      NaN         NaN     TownCity   NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN
9   2              NaN         NaN      NaN         NaN     NaN        NaN   NaN 03331     NaN
10  2              Nan         NaN      Nan         NaN     NaN        CityCounty  NaN     NaN
11  2              NaN         NaN      NaN         NaN     NaN        NaN   NaN   NaN     CN2222223
```

Desired output:

```
    record number   date      city_1    county_1  zip_code_1     city_2 county_2 zip_code_2  complaint_number
0   1              01/01/2009 CityVille CountyVille  01112       @      @          @          CN111112
1   2              02/01/2009 CityTown  TownCounty   02223       TownCity CityCounty  03331   CN222223
```

I've tried a few things, that I've found on SO, but they don't keep all record sets together as I need.

Comment: You can use `groupby` + `first`: `df.groupby('record number', as_index=False).first()`

Comment: @ShubhamSharma that is a breath of fresh air. I was circling this solution, but never quite got right to it. If you put it as an answer, I will gladly accept it. Thank you!

Comment: Megan, Glad it worked for you! This question is probably a dupe so I'll pass on adding the answer. Happy coding!

Comment: @ShubhamSharma it may be, or close, but I have scoured for the solution in past questions. I have not found your answer, nor quite my question. We will see. Thanks so much anyway!